# Why is it when you microwave cold coffee and then add milk it creates a foam head?

Tags: thermodynamics

As compared to when the coffee is just hot from brewing.  I suspect it has something to do with the way the microwaves are affecting the molecules of the coffee.

Comment: Foam heads are a chemical effect. I don't think there is any physics involved (except indirectly, through chemistry).

Comment: Question closed moments before I posted the Answer that follows here. You *may* be microwaving the coffee for *too* long. That is, you may be superheating the coffee. When you add the milk, the heat of the water in superheated coffee, which is at a temperature higher than 100C, may be enough to put bubbles into the milk.

If you *are* superheating the coffee, I recommend you microwave it for a shorter time, because superheated liquids can boil ***explosively***, causing very nasty scalds.

You haven't given quite enough information. How long are you microwaving your cup of coffee for?

Comment: @David If it's superheating, then it's Physics.

Comment: @Peter Morgan: I also don't understand why this question was closed...

Comment: ""Foam heads are a chemical effect. "" Ahh, only problem is, that "chemistry" dosn't know about that.

Comment: @ Peter Morgan, superheating in MWOs is often postulated, but not really possible for a pot of cold coffee. The impurities precipitated from the cold coffeee and the vibration of the rotation drive make superheating impossible.

Comment: @Peter Morgan: I usually heat a single mug of coffee for two minutes.

Comment: Two minutes isn't long enough. I usually microwave for 75 seconds, which isn't that different, and certainly doesn't get the coffee more than hot. I recall from a fairly reliable anecdote of a few years ago that microwaving *water* for five minutes can be enough, with an outcome that you certainly don't want to reproduce. As @Georg notes, however, enough impurities or motion will ensure that the liquid boils and doesn't overheat. As often, http://www.snopes.com/science/microwave.asp for a fairly well researched Answer.

Comment: @ Peter Morgan, I assume this is an effect from that specific "Milk". There are so many kinds of "milk" (as coffee additive) today, first thing were to clarify what that milk really is. If it contains some entrapped gas (air), the effect is possible with temperatures not exceeding 100 C

Comment: @Georg FYI, something *I* didn't know before just now, the space between the @ and the Peter resulted in me not being notified of your comment. Apparently it has to be "@Peter", not "@ Peter". I haven't anything substantive to add, it's probably just as well I didn't post my comment as an Answer.

Comment: The coffee gods are punishing you for microwaving your coffee, which is one of the 7 deadly coffee sins.